# when spark dataframe do add_months(), if the column is timestamp type, but return date type, how can I keep the hour:minute:seconds

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new with spark.
When I use `add_months()`, if the column is timestamp type it returns date type. How can I keep the `hour:minute:seconds` format?

```
df.where($"DEAL_ID" === "deal1" && $"POOL_ID" ==="pool_1")
  .select("LVALID_DEAL_DATE","LAST_PROCESS_DATE")
  .withColumn("test", add_months($"LAST_PROCESS_DATE", -3))
  .show
```

Output

```
|    LVALID_DEAL_DATE|   LAST_PROCESS_DATE|      test|
|2016-05-01 00:00:...|2016-08-01 19:38:...|2016-05-01|
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like add_months only supports Date types. If Timestamp type is passed it returns only Date part. I tried below code using unix_timestamp function and it converts HH:mm:ss to 00.

```
 df.withColumn("New Dates",unix_timestamp(add_months(df("Dates"),1)).cast("timestamp")).show
```

Comment: The question is about add_month function, even though the input type is timestamp, the out put type is date type, so it's no use to cast the input type to timestamp type

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer.I will see if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a trick here by converting timestamp to unix_epoch back and forth by first taking the time component in number of milliseconds, then adding it back to the new date we got after adding months using add_months

Assume we have a dataframe df as below

```
df.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
+---+
```

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType
val dfttimestamp = df.withColumn("StartDateTimeEpoch", lit(1573362092000L))
                                                .withColumn("StartDateTimeStamp", to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("StartDateTimeEpoch")/1000), "UTC"))

                                                .withColumn("StartDateTimeTruncated", unix_timestamp(col("StartDateTimeStamp").cast(DateType)) * 1000) //truncate time component by converting to Date
                                                .withColumn("StartTimeMillisDiff", col("StartDateTimeEpoch") - col("StartDateTimeTruncated")) //get time component in millis

                                                .withColumn("StartDate_NextYr", add_months(col("StartDateTimeStamp"),12)) //add 12 months to get next year, as Date column
                                                .withColumn("StartDateTimeEpoch_NextYr", unix_timestamp(col("StartDate_NextYr")) * 1000 + col("StartTimeMillisDiff")) // conver Date to unix-timestamp and add the prevous calculated diff in millis
                                                .withColumn("StartDateTimeStamp_NextYr", to_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("StartDateTimeEpoch_NextYr")/1000), "UTC"))
```

---

```
dfttimestamp.show()
dfttimestamp.printSchema()
```

---

```
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id|StartDateTimeEpoch| StartDateTimeStamp|StartDateTimeTruncated|StartTimeMillisDiff|StartDate_NextYr|StartDateTimeEpoch_NextYr|StartDateTimeStamp_NextYr|
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1|     1573362092000|2019-11-10 05:01:32|         1573344000000|           18092000|      2020-11-10|            1604984492000|      2020-11-10 05:01:32|
|  2|     1573362092000|2019-11-10 05:01:32|         1573344000000|           18092000|      2020-11-10|            1604984492000|      2020-11-10 05:01:32|
|  3|     1573362092000|2019-11-10 05:01:32|         1573344000000|           18092000|      2020-11-10|            1604984492000|      2020-11-10 05:01:32|
|  4|     1573362092000|2019-11-10 05:01:32|         1573344000000|           18092000|      2020-11-10|            1604984492000|      2020-11-10 05:01:32|
|  5|     1573362092000|2019-11-10 05:01:32|         1573344000000|           18092000|      2020-11-10|            1604984492000|      2020-11-10 05:01:32|
+---+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- StartDateTimeEpoch: long (nullable = false)
 |-- StartDateTimeStamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- StartDateTimeTruncated: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StartTimeMillisDiff: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StartDate_NextYr: date (nullable = true)
 |-- StartDateTimeEpoch_NextYr: long (nullable = true)
 |-- StartDateTimeStamp_NextYr: timestamp (nullable = true)
```